# What is the default AuthenticationManager in Spring-Security? How does it authenticate?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have the following bean defined:

```
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

I guess here Spring uses some default implementation of `AuthenticationManager`.

In my Java code I have:

```
@Resource(name = "authenticationManager")
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager; // specific for Spring Security

public boolean login(String username, String password) {
    try {
        Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
        if (authenticate.isAuthenticated()) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticate);             
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (AuthenticationException e) {         
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here `AuthenticationManager.authenticate(...)` is called. But I would like to know which implementation of `AuthenticationManager` Spring uses by default, and what its `authenticate(...)` does in order to authenticate (i.e., make sure that username matches password).

Could you explain this?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The `AuthenticationManager` is really just a container for authentication providers, giving a consistent interface to them all. In *most* cases, the default `AuthenticationManager` is more than sufficient.

When you call

```
.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password))`
```

it is passing the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` to the default `AuthenticationProvider`, which will use the `userDetailsService` to get the user based on username and compare that user's password with the one in the authentication token.

In general, the `AuthenticationManager` passes some sort of `AuthenticationToken` to the each of it's `AuthenticationProviders` and they each inspect it and, if they can use it to authenticate, they return with an indication of "Authenticated", "Unauthenticated", or "Could not authenticate" (which indicates the provider did not know how to handle the token, so it passed on processing it)

This is the mechanism that allows you to plug in other authentication schemes, like authenticating against an LDAP or Active Directory server, or OpenID, and is one of the main extension points within the Spring Security framework.

Comment: this doesn't answer the most concrete part of the question: "what's the name of the default implementation of the `AuthenticationManager` interface?" While @Ralph's answer below does. (`org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager`)

Comment: Since there's only 1 real `AuthenticationManager`, I focused on the meat of the question, which is "what does `authenticate` do?", which requires some background on how Spring is put together. In general, I've found that, a rich answer that covers the background that's driving the question is more useful than answering a specific question.

Comment: From what I see in Spring Boot, you don't have to explicitly set a Password Encoder in the UserDetailsService.  If you define it as a bean in you custom class that extends WebSecurityConfiguterAdapter, then it will automatically get picked up by the default DaoAuthenticationProvider.  Then the plain text password will be hashed and compared to the already hashed password that was previously stored.

Answer (score 42):

Spring Security ships only one real `AuthenticationManager` implementation:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager
```

This uses different `AuthenticationProvider` for the authentication tasks

The `AuthenticationManagerBeanDefinitionParser` is responsible to parse `<sec:authentication-manager>` its java doc states:

> Registers the central ProviderManager used by the namespace
>   configuration, and allows the configuration of an alias, allowing
>   users to reference it in their beans and clearly see where the name is
>   coming from.

It creates the `ProviderManager` and adds the specified provides. If no provides is specified in the xml, then it adds an `NullAuthenticationProvider`. This is at least a provider that does noting than preventing configuration exceptions.

Answer (score 6):

From [Spring Security Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/overall-architecture.html#core-services-authentication-manager):

> The default implementation in Spring Security is called *ProviderManager* and rather than handling the authentication request itself, it delegates to a list of configured *AuthenticationProvider*s, each of which is queried in turn to see if it can perform the authentication. Each provider will either throw an exception or return a fully populated *Authentication* object.

Information about *ProviderManager* can also be found in [Topical Guide - Spring Security Architecture](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture/):

> The most commonly used implementation of *AuthenticationManager* is
>   *ProviderManager*, which delegates to a chain of *AuthenticationProvider*
>   instances. An *AuthenticationProvider* is a bit like an
>   *AuthenticationManager* but it has an extra method to allow the caller
>   to query if it supports a given *Authentication* type...