# How to perform my own authentication (checking username and password typed by the user)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I implemented the `UserDetailsService` interface and override the `loadUserByUsername` method.

I thought that, inside  `loadUserByUsername`, I could get username and password, to check if they match username and password on the DB. But I can't understand how to get the password typed by the user, provided that it is possibile.

Probably, I'm implementing the wrong interface.

Is  `UserDetailsService` enough to do what I want to or I have to implement or extend something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername() is just to *load (retrieve)* the user details from the database - it isn't to do the password comparison.

The comparison happens in UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(). Then it calls to getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(), where the comparison occurs.

See this: [What is the default AuthenticationManager in Spring-Security? How does it authenticate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787409/what-is-the-default-authenticationmanager-in-spring-security-how-does-it-authen)

As for *replacing* `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, ask yourself what is your use case? what are you trying to do that the default implementation does not? maybe you do not have to replace it... anyways, you can see how to do it in [Spring's docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-web-filters.html#form-login-filter)

HTH

Comment: I can't find an example to configure my security.xml file after extending UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

Comment: what is your use case? what are you trying to do? maybe you do not have to replace it... anyways, you can see how to do it in Spring's docs http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-web-filters.html#form-login-filter

Comment: I want to check if  username and password typed by the user match username and password in the DB. I have to create my own "controller" because I need to check other db fields as well.

Comment: in this case i think you can stay with the original UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, but to ADD your own AuthenticationProvider. see this class: org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.java

Comment: was my answer helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

The `UserDetailsService` is just to retrieve the user details from the database - it isn't to do the password comparison.

If you want to do your own password comparison - you can implement your own `PasswordEncoder` (more specifically the `isPasswordValid(pass1,pass2,salt)` method but there are several you could extend - for example `Md5PasswordEncoder`

To wire your custom `PassordEncoder` you'll need something along the lines of this:

```
<authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="myPasswordEncoder"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: password encoding is a sub-case of authentication. There are cases where encoding is not required...