# Spring-Boot-Security: Custom Authenticator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am starting with Spring-Boot and have an application with WebSecurity.
Its working fine, I have InMemory Authentication with static user/passwords.

Now I have no need for DB or LDAP or ...

```
@Override
public void configure (AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
{
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication ()
        .withUser ("sam").
        .password (passwordEncoder ().encode ("secret"))
        .authorities ("ROLE_USER");
}
```

But I want to build a custom authenticator that uses dynamic data (e.g. password has current time in it).

How to implement a custom authenticator? How can I see username and password and implement a check?

Thanks for help!

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/26607703/9050514

Comment: i suggest you read about how FormLogin works https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide custom authentication you can refer to this link https://youtu.be/TNt3GHuayXs
and for seeing the username and password to check you can use principal object like this

```
 Object principal= SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

Let me know if you need more info