# Spring default Authentication internal working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I just started learning Spring and Spring Security and I have created a simple project by reading Spring Security documentation. I done the following java based configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("admin")
            .password("nimda")
            .roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll() 
            .antMatchers("/admin**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .and().formLogin();

        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

When I go for "/admin" it redirect me to the login page which I know spring generated with this default configuration and after login it will show the login page. Now my question is: login form is posted to "/login" and I did not defined any "AuthenticationManager" and "UserDetailService" which I read in documentation for custom configuration then how spring post the form and do the login process? Basically I want to know some detail of inner working of this default login process.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9788206/3447229 and documentation...

Answer (score 0):

When you use the *ConfigurerAdapter classes, there is a lot of stuff that goes on during context load. Spring will check if you have defined an AuthenticationManager, if you have not it will create a default one.

If you are really interested in what happens during the magic configuration step, you will probably have to look at the source code. For instance if you look at WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp() you can see it calls authenticationManager() in order to construct this bean.

```
protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
    if (!authenticationManagerInitialized) {
        configure(localConfigureAuthenticationBldr);
        if (disableLocalConfigureAuthenticationBldr) {
            authenticationManager = authenticationConfiguration
                    .getAuthenticationManager();
        }
        else {
            authenticationManager = localConfigureAuthenticationBldr.build();
        }
        authenticationManagerInitialized = true;
    }
    return authenticationManager;
}
```

In the old days you had to create all of the beans, yourself and wire them together, so we were more aware of how things fitted together. Now you either have to read the source, or copy from a guide, and hope you don't make any mistakes.

**Debug tip:** These days I look at the beans that exist after the context is loaded, and then I go back and set a breakpoint in the constructor of the AuthenticationManager implementation, then I can see the call-stack and how the initialisation work.

Comment: thanks for your time. I have POST method with URL "/login" but spring ignores that and executes his own default implementation. I need to call my own login post controller method.

Comment: What do you mean by your own login controller? Spring security has an AuthenticationManager which is typically configured using one or more AuthenticationProvider implementation. If you need to perform custom stuff, you may want to add your own AuthenticationProvider and implement the authenticate(Authentication) method. At this point the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken will have already been created, and you can inspect what the user put into the login form.

Comment: I mean that login form post url is "/login" and I have a controller method with "/login" and that method not hit when form is posted. So it means spring security give the form data direct to security stuff and does not hit my controller method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you are looking for, instead of using the builder to build an in-memory user details source, you can implement your own custom AuthenticationProvider.

```
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.authenticationProvider(new AuthenticationProvider() {
        @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
            String password = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
            String userName = (String) authentication.getCredentials();

            if ("user".equals(userName) && "password".equals(password)) {
                authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, password, Lists.newArrayList(new SimpleListProperty<GrantedAuthority>(null, "USER")));
                return authentication;
            }
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Incorrect username or password.");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Be aware that you can create your own Authentication implementation in case you need to add additional information, or you can use the details property on that every Authentication can have.